# Pass dim4 input to tflite in c# xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, tensorflow-lite

I have a simple image recognizer model in pb, and converted to tflite format.
**The input of the network is 1,224,224,3**

Created a **xamarin.forms android app**, and added the **tflite** nuget.
create an interpreter

`private Interpeter _tflite;`

I can load the model and the image

The image is stored in a float[] 1 dimensional array.

`float[] inputs = GetImageData();`

**when I try to run the tflite inference it gives me an exception because the input dim!=4**

`_tflite.run(inputs, outputs);  // outputs is an array to hold the result for classification`

So I try to store the image in a multidimensional array of float[1,224,224,3]

`float[,,,] input = GetImageData()`

but in this case at `_tflite.run(inputs, outputs)` the inputs can not be casted to Java.Lang.Object.

My question is, how can I pass my image to the network as input with shape 1,224,224,3?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Simply convert the float[] array to ByteBuffer
You must do the same for the output also, if the output is a multidim array

```
_outputBuffer = ByteBuffer.Allocate(1008 * 4);  // 1008 number of labels
_floatInBytData = new byte[floatValues.Length * sizeof(float)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(floatValues, 0, _floatInBytData, 0, _floatInBytData.Length);
using (var bf = ByteBuffer.Wrap(_floatInBytData))
{
    _outputBuffer.Rewind();
    bf.Rewind();
    _tflite.Run(bf, _outputBuffer);
}
float[] outputs = new float[1008];
byte[] o = new byte[1008 * 4];
_outputBuffer.Position(0);
_outputBuffer.Get(o);
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(o, 0, outputs, 0, o.Length);
```